# Как определять направление циклического сдвига двоичного кода на питоне?

Tags: python

Не могу понять, как определить направление циклического сдвига четырехпозиционного двоичного кода на питоне? Сдвиг происходи на 1 бит. Например, у цифры 6 (original_state) двоичный код 0110. Если сдвинуть код влево, получится 1100. Как определить, что мы сместили влево код?

```
def find_shift_direction(original, shifted):
    if len(original) != len(shifted):
        raise ValueError("Длины двух бинарных чисел должны быть одинаковыми")

    # Проверяем, есть ли различия в битах между двумя числами
    differences = [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(original, shifted)) if a != b]

    print(differences)

    if not differences:
        return "Нет сдвига"  # Нет различий - сдвига нет

    # Если есть различия, определяем направление сдвига
    if differences[0] > differences[-1]:
        return "Сдвиг влево"
    else:
        return "Сдвиг вправо"


# Пример использования
original_state = "0110" # Цифра 6
shifted_state = "1100"  # 1100 - Должен показать влево, 0011- вправо

direction = find_shift_direction(original_state, shifted_state)
print("Направление сдвига:", direction)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: должно работать только для 4-значных двоичных чисел?

Comment: По примеру похоже, что не просто сдвиг, а циклический сдвиг в 4 битах, и видимо сдвиг всегда на 1 бит. Добавьте текст задачи полностью.

Comment: Отметьте, что сдвиг не простой, а циклический. А для 5 и 10 в таблице что выбираться должно?

Comment: Если задача только для 4-значных числе, то можно сделать простой цикл. Будет максимум три итерации ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Сдвинуть исходное число налево, сравнить с результатом. Сдвинуть направо, сравнить с результатом. Где совпадёт там ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить три варианта, выбрать подходящий:

```
def find_shift(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return 'нет сдвига'
    if a[1:] + a[:1] == b:
        return 'сдвиг налево'
    if a[-1:] + a[:-1] == b:
        return 'сдвиг направо'
    return 'ничего непонятно'
```

Answer (score 1):

- Если итоговое число больше в 2 раза — сдвиг влево.
- Если итоговое число больше в 2^(n-1) раз (где n — длина числа в символах) — сдвиг вправо.
- Если итоговое число меньше в 2 раза — сдвиг вправо.
- Если итоговое число меньше в 2^(n-1) раз (где n — длина числа в символах) — сдвиг влево.

Список неисчерпывающий. Например, сдвиги для числа 9 в 4-значной записи сюда не попадают.

Answer (score 1):

Если гарантируется, что строка b является циклическим сдвигом а на один разряд:

```
print("Сдвиг в"+["право", "лево"][(a*2).find(b)==1])
```

Удваиваем первую строку. Если вторая является её циклическим сдвигом, то она встретится в удвоенной либо с позиции 1, либо с позиции len(b)-1

```
0110 и её сдвиги 0011 или 1100

01100110
 1100
   0011
```

Comment: Неочевидное решение, в хорошем смысле. Расскажите подробнее.

Comment: Вау, круто, а я и не знал что можно так... print(["123","456"][False]) кек. Плюсик вам за просвещение.